# Asynchronous io in c using windows API: which method to use and why does my code execute synchronous?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous, io

I have a C application which generates a lot of output and for which speed is critical. The program is basically a loop over a large (8-12GB) binary input file which must be read sequentially. In each iteration the read bytes are processed and output is generated and written to multiple files, but never to multiple files at the same time. So if you are at the point where output is generated and there are 4 output files you write to either file 0 or 1 or 2, or 3. At the end of the iteration I now write the output using `fwrite()`, thereby waiting for the write operation to finish. The total number of output operations is large, up to 4 million per file, and output size of files ranges from 100mb to 3.5GB. The program runs on a basic multicore processor.

I want to write output in a separate thread and I know this can be done with

1. Asyncronous I/O
2. Creating threads
3. I/O completion ports

I have 2 type of questions, namely conceptual and code specific.

### Conceptual Question

What would be the best approach. Note that the application should be portable to Linux, however, I don't see how that would be very important for my choice for 1-3, since I would write a wrapper around anything kernel/API specific. For me the most important criteria is speed. I have read that option 1 is not that likely to increase the performance of the program and that the kernel in any case creates new threads for the i/o operation, so then why not use option (2) immediately with the advantage that it seems easier to program (also since I did not succeed with option (1), see code issues below).

Note that I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689759/how-can-i-run-a-specific-function-of-thread-asynchronously-in-c-c, but I dont see a motivation on what to use based on the nature of the application. So I hope somebody could provide me with some advice what would be best in my situation. Also from the book "Windows System Programming" by Johnson M. Hart, I know that the recommendation is using threads, mainly because of the simplicity. However, will it also be fastest?

### Code Question

This question involves the attempts I made so far to make asynchronous I/O work. I understand that its a big piece of code so that its not that easy to look into. In any case I would really appreciate any attempt.

To decrease execution time I try to write the output by means of a new thread using WINAPI via `CreateFile()` with `FILE_FLAGGED_OVERLAP` with an overlapped structure. I have created a sample program in which I try to get this to work. However, I encountered 2 problems:

1. The file is only opened in overlapped mode when I delete an already existing file (I have tried using `CreateFile` in different modes (`CREATE_ALWAYS`, `CREATE_NEW`, `OPEN_EXISTING`), but this does not help).
2. Only the first `WriteFile` is executed asynchronously. The remainder of `WriteFile` commands is synchronous. For this problem I already consulted http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932. It seems that the problem I have is related to the fact that "any write operation to a file that extends its length will be synchronous". I've already tried to solve this by increasing file size/valid data size (commented region in code). However, I still do not get it to work. I'm aware of the fact that it could be the case that to get most out of asynchronous io i should `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, however I cannot get this to work as well.

Please note that the program creates a file of about 120mb in the path of execution. Also note that print statements "not ok" are not desireable, I would like to see "can do work in background" appear on my screen... What goes wrong here?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ASYNC  // remove this definition to run synchronously (i.e. using fwrite)

#ifdef ASYNC
    struct _OVERLAPPED *pOverlapped;
    HANDLE *pEventH;
    HANDLE *pFile;
#else
    FILE *pFile;
#endif

#define DIM_X   100
#define DIM_Y   150000

#define _PRINTERROR(msgs)\
 {printf("file: %s, line: %d, %s",__FILE__,__LINE__,msgs);\
 fflush(stdout);\
 return 0;}    \

#define _PRINTF(msgs)\
 {printf(msgs);\
  fflush(stdout);}      \

#define _START_TIMER       \
 time_t time1,time2;       \
 clock_t clock1;        \
 time(&time1);        \
 printf("start time: %s",ctime(&time1));  \
 fflush(stdout);

#define _END_TIMER\
 time(&time2);\
 clock1 = clock();\
 printf("end time: %s",ctime(&time2));\
 printf("elapsed processor time: %.2f\n",(((float)clock1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));\
 fflush(stdout);

double  aio_dat[DIM_Y] = {0};

double do_compute(double A,double B, int arr_len);

int main()
{
 _START_TIMER;

 const char *pName = "test1.bin";

    DWORD dwBytesToWrite;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

 int j=0;
 int i=0;
 int fOverlapped=0;

    #ifdef ASYNC
     // create / open the file
        pFile=CreateFile(pName,
            GENERIC_WRITE,   // open for writing
            0,               // share write access
            NULL,            // default security
            CREATE_ALWAYS,   // create new/overwrite existing
         FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,  // | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,   // overlapped file
         NULL);           // no attr. template

  // check whether file opening was ok
     if(pFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
   printf("%x\n",GetLastError());
   _PRINTERROR("file not opened properly\n");
  }

  // make the overlapped structure
     pOverlapped = calloc(1,sizeof(struct _OVERLAPPED)); 
  pOverlapped->Offset = 0;
  pOverlapped->OffsetHigh = 0;

   // put event handle in overlapped structure
  if(!(pOverlapped->hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL))){
   printf("%x\n",GetLastError());
   _PRINTERROR("error in createevent\n");
  }
 #else
  pFile = fopen(pName,"wb");
 #endif 

 // create some output 
 for(j=0;j<DIM_Y;j++){
     aio_dat[j] = do_compute(i, j, DIM_X);
 }

 // determine how many bytes should be written
  dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)sizeof(aio_dat);

 for(i=0;i<DIM_X;i++){ // do this DIM_X times

        #ifdef ASYNC
         //if(i>0){
      //SetFilePointer(pFile,dwBytesToWrite,NULL,FILE_CURRENT);
      //if(!(SetEndOfFile(pFile))){
      // printf("%i\n",pFile);
      // _PRINTERROR("error in set end of file\n");
      //}
      //SetFilePointer(pFile,-dwBytesToWrite,NULL,FILE_CURRENT);
      //}

      // write the bytes
      if(!(bErrorFlag = WriteFile(pFile,aio_dat,dwBytesToWrite,NULL,pOverlapped))){
       // check whether io pending or some other error
       if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_IO_PENDING){
    printf("lasterror: %x\n",GetLastError());
    _PRINTERROR("error while writing file\n");
       }
       else{
        fOverlapped=1;
       }
      }
          else{
       // if you get here output got immediately written; bad!
       fOverlapped=0;
      }

      if(fOverlapped){   
       // do background, this msgs is what I want to see
       for(j=0;j<DIM_Y;j++){
        aio_dat[j] = do_compute(i, j, DIM_X);
       }
       for(j=0;j<DIM_Y;j++){
        aio_dat[j] = do_compute(i, j, DIM_X);
       }

       _PRINTF("can do work in background\n");
      }
      else{
       // not overlapped, this message is bad
       _PRINTF("not ok\n");
      } 

                // wait to continue
      if((WaitForSingleObject(pOverlapped->hEvent,INFINITE))!=WAIT_OBJECT_0){
       _PRINTERROR("waiting did not succeed\n");
      }

      // reset event structure
      if(!(ResetEvent(pOverlapped->hEvent))){
       printf("%x\n",GetLastError());
       _PRINTERROR("error in resetevent\n");
      }

      pOverlapped->Offset+=dwBytesToWrite;

  #else
      fwrite(aio_dat,sizeof(double),DIM_Y,pFile);
   for(j=0;j<DIM_Y;j++){
    aio_dat[j] = do_compute(i, j, DIM_X);
   }
   for(j=0;j<DIM_Y;j++){
    aio_dat[j] = do_compute(i, j, DIM_X);
   }
  #endif
 }

 #ifdef ASYNC
     CloseHandle(pFile);
  free(pOverlapped);
 #else
     fclose(pFile);
 #endif

 _END_TIMER;

 return 1;
} 

double do_compute(double A,double B, int arr_len)
{
  int i;
  double   res = 0;
  double  *xA = malloc(arr_len * sizeof(double));
  double  *xB = malloc(arr_len * sizeof(double));

  if ( !xA || !xB )
   abort();

  for (i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
   xA[i] = sin(A);
   xB[i] = cos(B);
   res = res + xA[i]*xA[i];
  }

  free(xA);
  free(xB);

  return res;
}
```

### Useful links

- http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/cref_cls/common/cppref_asynchioC_aio_read_write_eg.htm
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/?ca=dgr-lnxw02aUsingPOISIXAIOAPI
- http://www.flounder.com/asynchexplorer.htm#Asynchronous%20I/O

I know this is a big question and I would like to thank everybody in advance who takes the trouble reading it and perhaps even respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work using the OVERLAPPED structure.

You're on the right track: the system is preventing you from writing asynchronously because every WriteFile extends the size of the file. However, you're doing the file size extension wrong. Simply calling SetFileSize will not actually reserve space in the MFT. Use the SetFileValidData function. This will allocate clusters for your file (note that they will contain whatever garbage the disk had there) and you should be able to execute WriteFile and your computation in parallel.

I would stay away from FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. You're after more performance with parallelism I presume? Don't prevent the cache from doing its job.

Comment: I've to fix my code with SetFileValidData, but unfortunately is not supported by the XP version I use. This seems kind of strange as the support website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) claims that XP is the minimum supported version. I guess then asynchronous I/O will not work for me using OVERLAPPED structures.

Comment: It should work on XP. I think you're missing the fact that your process token needs the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege to use this function. (How to acquire privileges is beyond the scope of this discussion I think - but it's very straightforward, google it.) See more on overlapped writes here: http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000765.html (Very insightful.)

Comment: Ok, since I was working on a system without admin rights this should have been my problem. Since it is more easy to use threads than to request admin rights I have rewritten the code using an output thread.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that you did not consider is a memory mapped file. Those are available on Windows and Linux. There is a handy Boost abstraction that you could use.

With a memory mapped file, every thread in your process could write its output to the file on its own time, assuming that the record sizes are known and each thread has its own output area.

The operating system will take care of writing the mapped pages to disk when needed or when it gets around to it or when you close the file. Maybe when you close the file. Now that I think about it, some operating systems may require that you call msync to guarantee it.

Comment: I did indeed not consider this option. After some quick search it indeed appears useful for me and I will investigate this further. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why you would want to write asynchronously. Doing things in parallel does not make them faster in all cases. If you write two file at the same time to the same disk, it will almost always be a lot faster. If that is the case, just write them one after another.

If you have some fancy drive like SSD or a virtual RAM drive, parallel writing *could* be faster. You have to create an file with at full size and then do your parallel magic.

Asynchronous writing is nice, but is done by any OS anyway. The potential gain for you is that you can do *other* things than writing to disk like displaying a progress bar. This is where multi-threading can help you.

So imho you should use serial writing or parallel writing to multiple disks.

hth

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed the reason I want to write asynchronously is so that the loop can immediately continue (so while output is being written I create new output). So if I understand correctly you would suggest using threads.

Comment: I think the async. version of `WriteFile()` is best here. You need only one call to the method, you can continue to produce new output and get informed when the output is written. Then you write out more data (to another file).

Comment: @Martin: why not have a dedicated "writer" thread that receives the data to be written and writes it separately from your calculation thread?

Comment: @wj32: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to try this as well and compare it with the asynchronous I/O method above.